# unable to persist newly added tags in xml using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- New XML document created with EditiX XML Editor (http://www.editix.com) at Tue Mar 18 22:41:05 IST 2014 
-->
<html xsi:NamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml DM_Project.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <head>
        <title>title1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <fragment name="heading" id="heading1">
            <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        </fragment>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using LINQ to add another fragment tag to my xml file, which is:

```
XDocument xdocument = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\DM_Project.xml");
var id = "heading3";
var name="heading";
var content = "This is the data part";
var temp = xdocument.Descendants("fragment").First();
temp.Parent.Add(new XElement("fragment", content, new XAttribute("id", id), new XAttribute("name", name)));
var temp1 = xdocument.Descendants("fragment");
Console.WriteLine(temp1);
```

The result of the query is:

```
<fragment name="heading" id="heading1">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
</fragment> 
<fragment id="heading3" name="heading">This is the data part</fragment>
```

If one can observe a few fragment tag having id "heading3" is added. However, if the try to extract the fragment tags again, using the below query:

```
XDocument xdocument = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\DM_Project.xml");
var temp = xdocument.Descendants("fragment");
Console.WriteLine(temp);
```

The result is:

```
 <fragment name="heading" id="heading1">
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    </fragment>
```

The newly added tag is missing. How can I get the data to be persistant? Am I missing something here? Or, this entire approach is itself wrong?

I am using LINQPad to test my queries.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saving document back to file. After you finished editing it call [XDocument.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DM_Project.xml";
XDocument xdocument = XDocument.Load(path);
// modify document
xdocument.Save(path);
```

Next time when you will execute your code (i.e. load document and query it) new elements will be there.